# Sending PHP array to DataTables JS library

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, datatables

Im trying to send a php array to the JS Datatable library.

I'm using this example:
https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/simple.html

However, since I'm just trying to test the functionality, I'm not fetching data from a database.

So here is my php code, basically:

```
$data_fmt['data'][] = array("TEST");
echo json_encode( $data_fmt );
```

Which gives an array like:

```
{
    "data": [
        ["TEST"]
    ]
 }
```

Now, on the Ajax/JS side, I have the following code:

```
$('#my_dt_table').DataTable( {                                                                                                                                                                                         
 "processing": true,                                                                                                                                                                                                  
 "serverSide": true,                                                                                                                                                                                                  
 "ajax": "my_php_script.php"                                                                                                                                                                                            
 } );
```

In the HTML I have:

```
<table id='my_dt_table' class='display' style='width:100%'>                                                                                                                                                            
<thead>                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
  <tr>                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
    <th>Column Title</th>                                                                                                                                                                                              
  </tr>                                                                                                                                                                                                            
 </thead>                                                                                                                                                                                                             
 <tfoot>                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
   <tr>                                                                                                                                                                                                    
     <th>Column Title</th>                                                                                                                                                                                         
   </tr>                                                                                                                                                                                                            
 </tfoot>                                                                                                                                                                                                       
</table>
```

Although the JSON is correct, I have the following error:

> DataTables warning: table id=my_dt_table- Invalid JSON response. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/1

What am I doing wrong ???

Thanks

Comment: Is your PHP in the same file as the HTML?  You seem to be responding with your actual HTML table.

Comment: @PatrickQ No, it's not in the same file as the html

Comment: So what is the exact and complete response you see in your browser's developer tools network tab for this request?

Answer (score 0):

If you return the JSON, please add the JSON header, also, make sure that you do not output anything before, and anything after `echo json_encode()`.

Try something like that:

```
<?php
$data = [
    'data' => [ [ 'TEST' ] ]
];
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($data);
```

Then use some tools, or the browser built-in developer tools or an extension like Postman, send the GET request and fetch that file to verify that your file returns the correct JSON response.

Answer (score 0):

change the server side script

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');

$data=array();
$data[] =array("TEST");//a row
$data[] =array("TEST 1");//a row with single colum
$data[] =array("TEST 2",'TEST 3');//a row double colum you can add more
print_r(json_encode(array('data'=>$data)));
```